# How to access to a multidimensional row by row?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to access to a multidimensional row by row in java but I am unable to achieve it.

I have this code but it prints out the array column by column:

```
for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<array[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(array[i][j]);
    }
}
```

So, for instance if I have this array:

```
[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]
```

How can I print it out in this way?

```
adg
beh
cfi
```

Full code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class forcabruta {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] words = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', ' '};
        String text;
        System.out.print("Enter a text to decode: ");
        text = keyboard.nextLine();
        char[][] combinations = new char[text.length()][words.length];
        for(int i = 0; i<text.length(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<words.length; j++) {
                if(words[j] == text.charAt(i)) {
                    for(int k = 1; k<words.length; k++) {
                        combinations[i][k] = words[Math.floorMod(j-k, 27)];
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; i<combinations.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<combinations[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(combinations[j][i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will the inner arrays always have the same length (three in your example)? If not then what should happen if you had, for example `[["a"], ["b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]`?

Comment: No, it will have always the same length for columns but not for rows. So, for instance sometimes I will have ```[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]```, ```[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]``` or ```[["a", "b", "c"]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Be careful of switching index!

For example, this would throw an error.

```
String[][] array = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}, {"j", "k"}};

for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j<array[i].length; j++) {
       System.out.print(array[j][i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

### Better is this:

```
String[][] array = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}, {"j", "k"}};

int maxColCount = 0;
int i = -1;
do {
    i++;
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
       if (array[j].length > i) {
          System.out.print(array[j][i]);
       }
       if (array[j].length > maxColCount) {
          maxColCount = array[j].length;
       }
    }
    System.out.println();
} while (i < maxColCount);
```

The basic idea is that you don't know how many columns you have, you will have to find it out yourself while doing the work. But you also have to check each time if the current row has so many columns or not before accessing it.

### If the amount of columns is always the same, this should suffice.

```
String[][] array = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}};
for(int i = 0; i < array[0].length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(array[j][i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But it will always have the same lenght of columns, it will only have a different lenght of rows. So, for instance sometimes I will have ```[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h", "i"]]```, ```[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"]]``` or ```[["a", "b", "c"]```

Comment: @AdriánT95 I fixed it now, could you check?

Answer (score 1):

You almost did it. Just replace:

```
System.out.print(array[i][j]);
```

to this:

```
System.out.print(array[j][i]);
```

---

**UPD 1:**
So your code becomes:

```
String[][] array = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}};
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(array[j][i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I already have tried to do it in this way, but I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3

Comment: Please, post the full code, which leads to that exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that [ArrayOutOfBoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html) is not thrown by not mixing rows and columns indices.
You have to start your loop on column index and then nest the rowIndex loop into that column index loop.
Here is how it works.

```
String[][] array = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d", "e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}, {"j", "k", "l"}};
    for(int colIndex= 0; colIndex < array[0].length; colIndex++){
        for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < array.length; rowIndex++){
            System.out.print(array[rowIndex][colIndex]);
        }
    }
```